# Brexit reference in Hao jile / Have A Nice Day

Tags: reference, have-a-nice-day

I just finished watching [Hao jile / Have A Nice Day](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt6451304).  According to [Mubi](https://mubi.com/showing/have-a-nice-day), [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/film/2018/mar/23/have-a-nice-day-review-liu-jian), [Variety](https://variety.com/2017/film/reviews/have-a-nice-day-review-hao-ji-le-1201984875/) and others, it contains many references:

> there are visual and verbal references to everything from “The Godfather” to “Rocky” to “Deadpool” to Mark Zuckerberg, Donald Trump, Steve Jobs, Brexit, and Bill Gates

I've seen references to The Godfather, Rocky, Zuckerberg, Trump, Jobs, and Gates.  However, I have not noticed the reference to Brexit, even though I was warned of it in advance and was looking for it.  Where is it?